# What is QT-Creator's equivalent to WinForms Dock-Fill?

Tags: layout, qt-creator, qt-designer, qtreeview, qtwidgets

I have a `QTreeView` widget placed inside a `QDockWidget`:

[image]

I want to set the properties of the `QTreeView`, that it automatically fills the whole available client drawing area (similar as WinForms DockFill property).

How can this be achieved with the QT-Designer?

---

<sub>**Note:** I've been playing around with the `QTreeView`s **sizePolicy** properties. If these are set to *Expanding* (as is the default) the accepted answer works out out of the box.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt Designer, right-click the dock-widget, and then select Lay out -> Lay Out Vertically from the menu. Or you can just click on the dock-widget to select it, and then use the equivalent layout toolbar buttons.

If you want to maximise the space taken up by the tree-view, select the first child widget of the dock widget (it will probably be shown as **dockWidgetContents** in the Object Inspector pane). Then scroll down to the bottom of the Property Editor, and reset all the margins to zero.

Comment: Unfortunately that choice isn't available from the Layout menu. The only choice there is _Adjust Size_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ. As I said, you need to select the **dock-widget**, not the tree-view. You can only set layouts on container widgets.

Comment: I did as you told and the `QTreeView` resizes with the `QDockWidget` now But it doesn't fill the whole client drawing area, which is what I'm finally after. Any other advice to achieve that?

Comment: Actually setting the `sizePolicy` horizontal and vertical values to `Expanding` seems to do the job + setting the margins as you said.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ. Those are the default values for a tree-view, so you must have changed them at some point.

Comment: Yeah. Could well be. I've been playing around a lot.